# Sumar minutos a fecha actual en java

Tags: java

Tengo un problema a la hora de obtener una nueva fecha en el calendario tras sumarle unos minutos a la actual.

Comienzo obteniendo la fecha actual:

```
java.util.Date fechaActual = new java.util.Date();
```

Mediante una función que he creado y que recibe 4 parámetros (Fecha actual, días, horas y minutos), quiero calcular la nueva fecha. Para ello hago esto:

```
Date nueva_fecha = sumarDiasAFecha(fechaActual, days, hours, minutes);

public static Date sumarDiasAFecha(Date fecha, int dias, int horas, int minutos){                       

            if (dias==0 && horas==0 && minutos==0) {
                return fecha;
            }


            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(fecha); 

            //pasamos todo a minutos

            int total_minutos = (dias*24*60) + (60*horas) + minutos;

            calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, total_minutos);
            return calendar.getTime(); 
        }
```

Posteriormente paso la fecha de Date a Calendar y trabajo con ella para obtener una fecha:

```
Calendar fecha_calendar = DateToCalendar(nueva_fecha);

int anyo = fecha_calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int mes = fecha_calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int dia = fecha_calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int hour = fecha_calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int minute = fecha_calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

String mes_fecha = "";
if (mes < 10) {
     mes_fecha = "0"+mes;
} else {
     mes_fecha = String.valueOf(mes);
}

 String dia_fecha = "";
 if (dia < 10) {
       dia_fecha = "0"+dia;
 } else {
       dia_fecha = String.valueOf(dia);
 }

 String hour_fecha = "";
 if (hour < 10) {
       hour_fecha = "0"+hour;
 } else {
       hour_fecha = String.valueOf(hour);
 }

 String hour_minute = "";
 if (minute < 10) {
       hour_minute = "0"+minute;
 } else {
       hour_minute = String.valueOf(minute);
 }

 String fecha_total = String.valueOf(anyo) + "-" + mes_fecha + "-" + dia_fecha + " " + hour_fecha + ":" + hour_minute + ":00";
```

El código me funciona para el día año y mes, pero las horas no, y no entiendo el motivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo pronto deberías cambiar, los formatos de las horas para trabajar de forma numérica.

```
int hour = fecha_calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
```

a

```
   int hour = fecha_calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

Comment: Pues creo que con esto se me ha solucionado el problema que tenía, lo estoy comprobando a fondo.

Comment: ahora recuerda que las horas te serán de 0 a 23 (formato de 24 hs)